# Asking a more financial than programming-related question on StackOverflow

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I've just deleted [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14099564/whats-the-financial-value-of-a-complex-algorithm) I made on Stack Overflow regarding how much certain **algorithms** should cost. I got immediately downvoted a couple of times and have been told to read the FAQ.

While I do know SO is programming-oriented, I understood its userbase is much more likely to know the answer than on any business-related community.

Where should I ask this question? Is there an appropriated StackExchange website for that?

Comment: Screenshot? It's hard for us to tell until you let us know what the q was.

Comment: Does my question get stored somewhere? I didn't take any screenshots before deleting it.

Comment: Have you still the URL? Users with at least 10K rep can still see it if they have the URL.

Comment: Well, yeah, it's visible to 10k users. If you give us the URL, someone can get a screenshot of it.

Comment: I believe this is it: [What's the (financial) value of a complex algorithm?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14099564/whats-the-financial-value-of-a-complex-algorithm) (10k only)

Comment: @Mat found faster than myself, that's the one :)

Comment: (And no, I don't think you'll find a Stack Exchange site that will take that question. How much, on average, would an algorithm implementation be sold for isn't answerable IMO.)

Comment: I was one that down-voted that question and flagged for attention. Apart from the OT aspect if I remember correctly (don't have rep to view now) it was very vague in the first place. It was almost like asking why a baseball player in one country can be paid a thousand times more than a doctor in another country.

Comment: I'm with @peterj, it depends entirely on the company and even then that companies priorities... There is no one, or even a million, answer(s).

Comment: @PeterJ I disagree. I asked what would be a reasonable price for four types of algorithms. That's a pretty straight forward question, just not enough programming-related for SO. I also had added the Netflix Prize program that offered a lot of money for an algorithm and wondered if every algorithm should be as pricey — it was just a side note, not the main question, which you and other people seem to have misunderstood (e.g. your baseball player example).

Comment: Even if it were about programming, a question *so* hypothetical as "If a company wants to buy the following [things] How much, on average, would each cost?" is so unanswerable as to be non-constructive.